# Creating script to bulk rename files with Powershell SQL Query based on file name

Tags: sql, powershell

I am working on creating a script that will scan through a folder structure for .dat files and use the file name to perform a SQL query for information about the file file and rename the file with this data.

I have created the following pieces of code but am having trouble getting them working together.

Creating list of files using get-childitem

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Kaseya\Storage\" -recurse -filter "*.dat" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Which is generating expected results of:

```
085852f7-314f-4748-958b-97f6f74abedf.dat
0b0cef66-2553-4a5c-a808-7fee38d742f0.dat
0ce00b36-4920-4a22-913f-2281f36ea32c.dat
0d583f3c-13e1-45b2-8b93-e0b9fa7939f2.dat
15c58336-8f5c-4951-9b7f-43f3f8fe10ed.dat
1c58a339-55c1-4620-a2b6-3135b9dea17e.dat
1ca0d9a3-0510-44f3-bb47-25f42b607fe7.dat
1eacb9bb-5c8d-4b3b-8adb-67bf50da8778.dat
22782d89-0d09-4d30-b344-1d224e5138d4.dat
2519d974-b36a-44e3-8717-75b024d6ed80.dat
26c02398-e4b1-461a-aef0-e3af4254648b.dat
2c910f9e-4319-4769-a9a2-436cdacf1205.dat
2fb25b6f-aa10-4b13-80c6-82b5a70215e6.dat
31af4f7e-9de9-40fc-aed6-6d6a790e015e.dat
35df29b3-8760-41ed-806c-d77b81d02600.dat
3b93d671-5416-471a-a114-7a2a0fa0001a.dat
41d9cad9-121a-49f2-84cb-c0a501c65c63.dat
```

Then I am attempting to bring this information into a ForEach and loop through a SQL query.

```
    ForEach($file in $files){

    $Global:SCCMSQLSERVER = "nisql01" 
    $Global:DBNAME = "ksubscribers" 
    Try 
    { 
    $SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection 
    $SQLConnection.ConnectionString ="server=$SCCMSQLSERVER;database=$DBNAME;Integrated Security=True;" 
    $SQLConnection.Open() 
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Failed to connect SQL Server:")  
    } 

    $SQLCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
    $SQLCommand.CommandText = "select a.FileName,a.AgentFileId,b.machName FROM Storage.AgentFile as a JOIN machNameTab b ON a.AgentGuid = b.agentGuid where a.AgentFileID = @fileidifo"
    $SQLCommand.Parameters.Add("fileidifo", $file);
    $SQLCommand.Connection = $SQLConnection 

    $SQLAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLCommand                  
    $SQLDataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
    $SqlAdapter.fill($SQLDataset) | out-null 

    $userdateinfo = $data[0] 
    $machinenameinfo = $data[2]
    $userdateinfo
    $machinenameinfo
    $SQLConnection.close()

}
```

However I this is not working, I am unsure I have the declare variable and code correct and also i need to strip the .dat from the file name as the data in the table looks like this.

[SQL Query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0bDO.png)

Once I have that portion working I will be using Rename-Item to rename the item with the information pulled from the SQL Query with something like this:

```
Rename-Item "C:\Kaseya\Storage\1\Agents\791729858106897\1\1\a2955462-52fb-4727-a7ea-21ddf019e5ea.dat" -NewName $machinenameinfo-$userdateinfo
```

However I am unsure how to get the full path of the file again as i dont think its still part of $file since i have it filtered down to only select the Name property.

Comment: Please clarify what is not working - do you get an error or what happens?

Comment: I am getting the following: `Cannot index into a null array.
At line:22 char:27
+     $userdateinfo = $data[ <<<< 0]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Cannot index into a null array.
At line:23 char:30
+     $machinenameinfo = $data[ <<<< 2]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (2:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray`

Comment: `$data` is nowhere defined, at least not in the code you posted. I assume it's supposed to be `$SQLDataset`?